# cannot copy from one stage to another in multi stage docker build

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, taurus

I want to create and execute performance tests against the application. For now, my idea was to use multi-stage build on the first stage to build the application, on the second - build the performance testing and start both application and performance tests in the same container.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
# build stage
FROM gradle:jdk11
ARG ARTIFACT_PATH=json-comparison-application/build/libs
ARG ARTIFACT_NEW=app.jar
ARG ARTIFACT_OLD=json-comparison-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN echo ${ARTIFACT_PATH}
RUN apt-get install git && git clone https://github.com/xxxx/json-comparison.git
WORKDIR json-comparison
RUN chmod +x gradlew && \
    ./gradlew clean build -x pmdMain -x spotbugsMain -x checkstyleMain --no-daemon && \
    cd ${ARTIFACT_PATH} && mv ${ARTIFACT_OLD} ${ARTIFACT_NEW}

# performance test stage
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# simplified adoptopenjdk/11 without CMD entry point, probably better move to some external dockerfile
ARG ESUM='6dd0c9c8a740e6c19149e98034fba8e368fd9aa16ab417aa636854d40db1a161'
ARG BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.5%2B10/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.5_10.tar.gz'
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
ENV JAVA_VERSION jdk-11.0.5+10
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl ca-certificates fontconfig locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN set -eux; \
    curl -LfsSo /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${BINARY_URL}; \
    echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk; \
    cd /opt/java/openjdk; \
    tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    rm -rf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk \
    PATH="/opt/java/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
# custom part of the stage
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python default-jre-headless python-tk python-pip python-dev \
                       libxml2-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev net-tools && \
    pip install bzt
WORKDIR /home/tmp
ARG ARTIFACT_PATH=json-comparison/json-comparison-application/build/libs
ARG ARTIFACT_NEW=app.jar
RUN echo ${ARTIFACT_PATH}
COPY --from=0 /${ARTIFACT_PATH}/${ARTIFACT_NEW} .
# prototype for test
CMD ["bzt", "quick_test.yml"]
```

But it fails during `build` with error

```
Step 23/24 : COPY --from=0 /${ARTIFACT_PATH}/${ARTIFACT_NEW} .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f227e7b77fba105ba0769aa355458900d202add59c98583f0fd0936cbf4dfc11/merged/json-comparison/json-comparison-application/build/libs/app.jar: no such file or directory
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight the problem comes from the (absolute vs. relative) paths of the `.jar` in your two stages.

Can you verify that they are the same?

For example, you may replace the last command of the first stage with

```
RUN […] && \
  cd ${ARTIFACT_PATH} && mv ${ARTIFACT_OLD} ${ARTIFACT_NEW} && readlink -f ${ARTIFACT_NEW}
```

and relaunch the build. If you don't obtain

> `/json-comparison/json-comparison-application/build/libs/app.jar`

but a longer path, then you'll know the correct path to put in `ARTIFACT_PATH` within the second stage…

Alternatively, you could just get rid of the relative path in the first stage and replace `WORKDIR json-comparison` with:

```
WORKDIR /json-comparison
```

As an aside, it can be useful to name your build stages in the following way:

```
FROM gradle:jdk11 as builder
[…]

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as test
[…]
```

Then, this allows you to only build the first stage by running:

```
$ docker build --target builder -t $IMAGE_NAME .
```

Comment: It seems the artifact is on `/home/gradle/json-comparison...` path probably because `gradle` image sets `WORKDIR` as `/home/gradle`

Comment: @lapots Yes, actually `WORKDIR $dir` can be viewed as a Dockerfile equivalent to `mkdir -p $dir && cd $dir`. And I'd say a good practice is to prefer using an absolute path for $dir instead of a relative path.